# Using CockroachDB's RESTORE command, how can I restore a database into another database name?

Tags: cockroachdb

I have a backup of a CockroachDB database named foo, and I would like to restore it on my cluster but have the database name be bar. When I try `RESTORE DATABASE foo ... WITH into_db=bar`, I get an error `cannot use "into_db" option when restoring database(s)`. What's the right way to do this, then?

Answer (score 2):

`into_db` can only be applied at the table level, but there's a simple workaround--apply it to the wildcard expansion of all tables:

```sql
RESTORE TABLE foo.* ... WITH into_db=bar
```

is valid and will do what you want.

In the upcoming 22.1 release, [you'll instead be able to do](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/dev/restore.html#rename-a-database-on-restore)

```sql
RESTORE DATABASE foo ... WITH new_db_name=bar -- 22.1+ only
```